# Properties of Expectations with Joint Distributions and Independence

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, independence

Suppose I have a random vector $(X, Y)$ governed by some $f_{XY}(x,y)$, and another random vector $(A, B)$ with the exact same joint distribution of $(X,Y)$, but $(A, B)$ is independent of $(X,Y)$. If I know the $E[X] = E[Y] = c$, can I also assume that $E[A] = c$ because of independence and the same joint distribution?

Comment: Also if they were dependent. If two random variables have the same distribution, they have the same expectation.

Comment: @YJT so is what I said correct??

Comment: Yes, indeed....